# Reisz Kakutani & The Jordan Decomposition Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $M(X)$ denote the collection of all complex valued regular Borel measures on $X$ with finite total variation.

If $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the collection of cont. maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the sup norm, then (a version of) Reisz Kakutani says for $\varphi: C(X,\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a positive linear functional, there exists a unique $\mu \in M(X)$ real valued such that $$\varphi(f) = \int_{X} f \: d\mu \: \: \forall f \in C(X,\mathbb{R})$$ with $||\varphi|| = ||\mu|| = |\mu|(X)$.

Applying the Jordan Decomposition theorem to $\mu$ yields nonegattive measures $\mu^{+},\mu^{-} \in M(X)$ with $\mu=\mu^{+}-\mu^{-}$ and $||\mu||=||\mu^{+}||+||\mu^{-}||$.

Then the correspondence given in Reisz Kakutani yields two positive linear functionals $\varphi^{+}, \varphi^{-} \in C(X,\mathbb{R})^{*}$ with $\varphi = \varphi^{+}-\varphi^{-}$, namely the linear functionals represented by $$\varphi^{+}(f) = \int_{X} f \: d\mu^{+}, \: \: \text{and} \: \: \varphi^{-}(f) = \int_{X} f \: d\mu^{-}.$$

Clearly $||\varphi|| \leq ||\varphi^{+}|| + ||\varphi^{-}||$, but i'm a bit lost on showing an equality here.  Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Note that $\|\phi\| = \sup_A \mu(1_A) -  \inf_A \mu(1_A)$. Use the Hahn decomposition to show this equals $\|\phi^+\| + \| \phi^- \|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$\|\varphi\|=\|\mu\|=\|\mu_+\|+\|\mu_-\| = $$
$$
= \|\varphi_+\|+\|\varphi_-\|.
$$

Comment: As usual, I try and overcomplicate things, thank you!